# Laravel detach Pivot tables

Tags: laravel, request, pivot-table, laravel-facade

I'm new with Laravel and I'm having problems while I try to detach some values from my pivot tables.

The pivot tables I'm woking with are:
excercise_workout (ejercicio_rutina) & excise_day (ejercicio_dia) (those tables have just two id's each one). The relations are ManyToMany. **A workout have a lot of days and a day have a lot of excercises.**

**I've created these routes:**

Route::resource('rutinas','RutinasController');
Route::delete('rutinas.destroyEjercicio/{id}','RutinasController@destroyEjercicio');

I have this button that is a form and call the delete:

```
                {!! Form::open([
                    'method' => 'DELETE',
                    'action' => [ 'RutinasController@destroyEjercicio', $ejercicio->id ]
                ]) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Borrar Ejercicio', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The destroyEjercicio is the part I don't know how to hadle with:

```
public function destroyEjercicio($id)
{
    $ejercicio = Ejercicio::findOrFail($id);


    dias()->$ejercicio->detach($id);

   //EXAMPLE DELETE WITH QUERY 
   // DB::delete('delete from toy_user where toy_id = ? AND user_id = ? AND status = 0', array($toy->id,Auth::id()));

    return redirect('rutinas');

}
```

I recieve this error when I try to submit the delete form:
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\dias()

I've tried a lot of other methods but I don't know how to do it.

I need to know the ID of the day and the ID of the excercise I want to delete. And I don't know how the past it by the post request.

**UPDATE -> THIS IS THE FORM I DO NOT HAVE INPUTS TO REQUEST...**

```
@foreach ($rutina->dias as $dia)
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Ejercicios para el <strong>{{ $dia->nombre }}</strong>
            <hr>
            @foreach ($dia->ejercicios as $ejercicio)
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ $ejercicio->nombre }}</li>
                </ul>
                {!! Form::open([
                    'method' => 'DELETE',
                    'action' => [ 'RutinasController@destroyEjercicio', $ejercicio->id ]
                ]) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Borrar Ejercicio', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
             @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `foreach ($rutina->dias as $dia)
       <hr>
       foreach ($dia->ejercicios as $ejercicio)
        <ul>
         <li>{{ $ejercicio->nombre }}</li>
        </ul>
        {!! Form::open([
                     'method' => 'DELETE',
                     'action' => [ 'RutinasController@destroyEjercicio', $ejercicio->id ]
                 ]) !!}
                     {!! Form::submit('Borrar Ejercicio', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                 {!! Form::close() !!}
        endforeach
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 endforeach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this the following way. First I create this new route:

```
Route::post('rutinas.destroyEjercicio/{ejercicioId}/{diaId}', [
'as' => 'destroy', 
'uses' => 'RutinasController@destroyEjercicio'
]);
```

You must add this array at the form:

```
                {!! Form::open([
                    'method' => 'POST',
                  *******'route' => ['destroy', $ejercicio->id, $dia->id]******
                ]) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Borrar Ejercicio', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then in your controller you pass the two id's that you need:

```
public function destroyEjercicio($ejercicioId, $diaId)
{
    $ejercicio = Ejercicio::findOrFail($ejercicioId);
    $ejercicio->dias()->detach($diaId);
    return redirect('rutinas');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
public function destroyEjercicio($ejercicioId, $diasId)
{
    $ejercicio = Ejercicio::findOrFail($ejercicioId);

    $ejercicio->dias()->detach($diasId);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships

**Update**

How to use Request object. If you're using forms, Reuqest object will contain all form fields. Just do something like this:

```
public function destroyEjercicio(Request $request)
{
    $ejercicioId = $request->get('ejercicioIdField');

    $diasId = $request->get('diasIdField');
```

Comment: I understand you and it have sense, but where I have to specify this $ejercicioId, $diasId ? On the form?

Comment: Usually you have a form which you fill and send it to `destroy()` method. So just make sure user fills day and exercise and pass the data. If you're using forms you can get data from Request object. Please check updated answer for example code.

Comment: I update so you can see my form i do not have inputs to request it's just a button inserted in every excercise